# angular 2 append directive after current component

Tags: typescript, angular

Say if I have following example component (note my-app is not application defining component that is used inside index.html)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [NavbarComponent, SidebarComponent],
    template: `
      <my-navbar></my-navbar>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <my-sidebar></my-sidebar> <!-- Append this after <my-app></my-app> -->
    `
})
```

I want to be able and use `<my-sidebar>` component and add information to it, however I want to display it after `<my-app>` instead of inside it. Is this at all possible in angular 2?

Comment: You could use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)... I don't know of any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your sidebar component as normal

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-sidebar',
  template: 'Sidebar'
})
class SidebarComponent{}
```

Then in your `AppComponent` you can use the `DynamicComponentLoader` to inject the `SidebarComponent` next to the `AppComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [NavbarComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <my-navbar></my-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
})
class AppComponent {
    constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
        dcl.loadNextToLocation(SidebarComponent, elementRef);
    }
}
```

The end result will be

```
<my-app>
  <my-navbar></my-navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</my-app>
<my-sidebar>Sidebar</my-sidebar>
```

Comment: do you have an working example, where did you get the DynamicComponentLoader?? from

Comment: @Xvegas The DynamicComponentLoader has been removed in the current version of angular. Check out the `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` and `ComponentFactoryResolver` for the same behaviour in today's versions of angular.

Comment: hi @SnareChops  I actually found a working sample thanks, on this one you can load dynamically components.http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXsIWykqKZi5r75VMtw2?p=preview